# How do i create a custom installer for an arbitrary composer type

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Composer is a PHP package manager. I have looked through the documentation here: http://getcomposer.org/

I am looking to create a custom type "symfony2-assets" and have them install to the "web" directory instead of to the "vendor" directory.

I know i can change the config key "vendor-dir" to web to accomplish this but that also installs all of the other packages in there and i need those ones in the vendor directory.

If anyone has a good tutorial they have come across on this or knows how to do it, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a package with type `composer-installer`, and require it in your application. In theory packages of the type you want to handle (`symfony2-asset2`) should require the installer to make sure it's installed first.

Your installer can just inherit from LibraryInstaller and put files wherever you want.

This should work for now, but in the long term I hope we can find a somewhat generic way of handling web assets in Composer. Our main focus is still PHP code for now though.

Comment: not what i was hoping to find, but answers the question thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can add [post-install-cmd](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#scripts) script that that will copy/make symlink to the web directory.

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for. in composer there is a LibraryInstaller.php that handles installing all packages with type Library, im wondering how i would go about making a new one of those and how i would tell composer to use that.
https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php